# Calling Applicationcontext.xml from Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have existing application using spring application and with .properties files for the place holders in the xml file.
   Now, we are planning to use spring boot application to import spring applicationcontext.xml with out disturbing existing business logic. below are the changes

**1. Main Service class:**

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.config")
@RestController
@EnableConfigurationProperties(servicesProperties.class)
public class servicesApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(servicesApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(servicesApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() {
        return "This is the first program in fixedservices!";
    }
 }
```

**2. in configuration class giving like below**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
public class ApplicationLoading
```

**3. below is my applicationContext.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.2.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd 
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd"
    default-lazy-init="true">
        <context:component-scan
            base-package="com.model" />
        <!-- CXF QPS SERVICE CLIENT SPRINT SETUP (START) -->
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlPropertiesFactoryBean">
            <property name="locations">
                <list>
                    <value>classpath:config/application-local.yml
                    </value>
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
        </bean>

            <jaxws:client id="qpsServiceClient"
            serviceClass="com.qpssoapservice.client.QPSService"
            address="${qps_url}">
            <jaxws:outInterceptors>
                <bean class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <map>
                            <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken" />
                            <entry key="user" value="${username}" />
                            <entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordText" />
                            <entry key="passwordCallbackRef" value-ref="passwordCallback" />
                        </map>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </jaxws:outInterceptors>
        </jaxws:client>

        <bean id="passwordCallback"
            class="com.qpssoapservice.callback.ClientPasswordCallback">
            <property name="userName" value="${username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${password}" />
        </bean>

        <bean name="QPSManager" id="QPSManager" class="com.qps.QPSManager">
            <property name="qpsServiceClient" ref="qpsServiceClient" />
        </bean>

    </beans>
```

Only change is earlier i am using property file now i have configured YML file.

**below is my YML file properties:**

```
    spring:

          profiles:

                  active: local

    qps_url: https://sample.QPSSoapService

    username: abcd

    password: xyxys
```

i am facing error while deploying into tomcat. below is the error:

```
    17:11:24,955 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.springframework] to WARN
    17:11:24,955 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@5becdd30 - Propagating WARN level on Logger[org.springframework] onto the JUL framework
    17:11:24,955 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.springframework.web] to WARN
    17:11:24,955 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@5becdd30 - Propagating WARN level on Logger[org.springframework.web] onto the JUL framework
    17:11:24,955 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.thymeleaf] to WARN
    17:11:24,955 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@5becdd30 - Propagating WARN level on Logger[org.thymeleaf] onto the JUL framework
    17:11:24,955 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
    17:11:24,956 |-INFO in org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.SpringBootJoranConfigurator@163b1404 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

      .   ____          _            __ _ _
     /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
     \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
      '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
     =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
     :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.6.RELEASE)


    [WARN] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'methodValidationPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'methodValidationPostProcessor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.qpssoapservice.callback.ClientPasswordCallback] for bean with name 'passwordCallback' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.qpssoapservice.callback.ClientPasswordCallback
    Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'qpsServiceClient': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Class' for property 'serviceClass'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [com.qpssoapservice.client.QPSService]
    [ERROR] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor' threw an exception
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6bdc99a0: startup date [Mon Aug 21 17:11:25 PDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:414)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
        at `enter code here`org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.destroySingletons(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1030)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:556)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    [ERROR] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6bdc99a0: startup date [Mon Aug 21 17:11:25 PDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
```

Note: **QPSService, ClientPasswordCallback class calling from jar file by providing required properties.**

with out using import applicationcontext.xml it is working fine. and i can hit sample url like https://localhos:8080/. but when i have include import the problem is coming. did i need to give any other configuration to load and also i am suspecting place holders are not reading correctly but i may wrong.

Comment: `com.qpssoapservice.client.QPSService` and `com.qpssoapservice.callback.ClientPasswordCallback` are not on the classpath. The error is unambiguous. Are they in your war file?

Comment: Try something, if you go to servicesApplication class could you try to import the `com.qpssoapservice.client` packge  like this `import com.qpssoapservice.client.*;` does it give you a compilation error? if it is then `QPSService` and maybe `ClientPasswordCallback` are not in the classpath.

Comment: @Strelok u r right, this is my mistake. Thanks for response

Answer (score 0):

Thanks  to everyone. This is my mistake, the jar file is not there in war. Now the problem got resolved.